# Globally defined variables as function return

Tags: c

I  have function that returns pointer to day of week name when pass day of week number. I have feeling I do something illegal by using globally defined strings as function return. Is such style acceptable?

```
const char* const SUN_NAME = "Sun";
const char* const MON_NAME = "Mon";
const char* const TUE_NAME = "Tue";
const char* const WED_NAME = "Wed";
const char* const THU_NAME = "Thu";
const char* const FRI_NAME = "Fri";
const char* const SAT_NAME = "Sat";


    char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)
    {
        switch (day)
        {
            
        case SUN_NR :
            return SUN_NAME;
            break;
        case MON_NR :
            return MON_NAME;
            break;
        case TUE_NR :
            return TUE_NAME;
            break;
        case WED_NR :
            return WED_NAME;
            break;
        case THU_NR :
            return THU_NAME;
            break;
        case FRI_NR :
            return FRI_NAME;
            break;
        case SAT_NR :
            return SAT_NAME;
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
        }
    };
```

Comment: It is legal and acceptable. I'd put them in array though and get rid of the `switch/case`.

Comment: It should be `const char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)` instead of `char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)`. Otherwise it's OK. BTW: the second `const` in `const char* FRI_NAME = "Fri";` etc. is useless.

Comment: Why you want to separate inline strings `"Sun"`, `"Mon"` from `switch()`. Do you want to use them globally in the code? (referencing to `SUN_NAME`, `MON_NAME`)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Second `const` is not useless. I would like to be sure that nobody will  change content and pointer.

Comment: @shjeff  I will use `SUN_NAME, MON_NAME` in other functions. I don't want separate them from `switch()`

Comment: @vico you can even define them locally. And since these are *string literals*, the returned pointer will be still valid even outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what Eugene Sh said:

1. It is legal and acceptable.
2. I'd put them in array though:

EXAMPLE:

```
   const char * DaysOfWeekNames[] = {
     "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
   };

   enum DaysOfWeek {
     SUN_NR, MON_NR,TUE_NR, WED_NR, THU_NR, FRI_NR, SAT_NR
   };

   const char * dayOfWeekToChar(enum DaysOfWeek day)
   {
     return DaysOfWeekNames[day];
   }
```

Comment: I've suggested different naming... Also, I would consider making the array static inside the name-getter function, rather than exposing it for general use. Not sure about that though.

Comment: @einpoklum: thank you for your constructive suggestions - definitely appreciated :)  1) "Sun", "Mon", Tues", ... are all "days of the week" (plural).  Hence my naming preference.  It's merely a "preference".  2) Ideally, I'd split the code into two source files:  a) .h header (with enum and function prototype) and b) .c implementation (with static array *outside* of the function body).  3) Of course, if this were C++, I'd make the whole thing a "class" ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you do is OK, but it should be `const char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)`, because you return a pointer to a `const char*` and not a pointer to `char*`.

You could do this which is more or less the same as you do:

```
const char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)
{
  static const char* days[] =
  {
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    ...
  };

  return days[day];
}
```

However you should probably add some checks to make sure `day` is within the range `[0..6]` .

Comment: This is really clean! I have never considered this usage of static variables before... Thanks for the inspo

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't even have to be `static`, as the returned is a pointer to a string literal. It's just that `static` will reduce the runtime overhead (without `static` the array will have to be initialized each time the function is entered).

Comment: @squidwardsface `static` local variables (as `deys` here) have exactly the same lifetime as global variables, but they can only be accessed from the function where they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

This is an acceptable way of doing things. `strerror` is an example of this concept that is used in the C library (`strerror` translates values of `errno` to useable string descriptions of the error that occurred).

However, I would recommend one of two things. Either make it very clear in your documentation that the return value of this function IS NOT TO BE MODIFIED BY THE PROGRAMMER, or you can dynamically allocate a new string so that the calling function can safely modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables as return values of the functions, but I would not keep it as a global variable:

```
const char* dayOfWeekToChar(int day)
{
    static const char * DaysOfWeekNames[] = 
               {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    const char *result = NULL; 
    if(day >= 0 && day < 7) 
        result = DaysOfWeekNames[day];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say such style is sub-optimal. You should really just use an array.

```
const char * const daynames[7] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
```

with an `enum`  to access the values:

```
enum DaysOfTheWeek {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
};
```

And you can do for eg. `daynames[WEDNESDAY]` to get "Wed".

And if you want it to only done using the preprocessor:

```
#define DAY1 "SUN"
#define DAY2 "MON"
#define DAY3 "TUE"
#define DAY4 "WED"
#define DAY5 "THU"
#define DAY6 "FRI"
#define DAY7 "SAT"

#define GET_DAY(num) DAY##num
```

The first method is strongly recommended.

Comment: `const char const *` is the same as `const char *` or `char const *`. You probably meant `const char * const` or `char const * const`.